# How to run multiple django services in single Docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a Django project with a few microservices which heavily rely on django infrastructure itself and have to be started with:

```
python manage.py sevicename1
python manage.py sevicename2
python manage.py sevicename3
python manage.py sevicename4
python manage.py sevicename...
```

They all communicate with each other.
What is the proper way to run them in one Dockerfile all together?

Comment: Have you looked into docker-compose?

Comment: Each of your service should run in separate container. So you can create a Dockerfile per service and use docker-compose to start them up with correct networking.

Comment: Please see my thoughts below.

Comment: So you suggest reusage of the same source code in different containers?

Comment: Yes, build 1 image that has all the reqs and the code to run your app. Then run that image multiple times

Comment: How? The way I described below?

Comment: I mean how can I rerun the same container with different CMDs or Entrypoints?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to cut them out in separate containers.
I fount no better solution and did it in my docker-compose.yml through YAML anchors.

```
dg: &dg
  image: python:3.7.6-alpine
   command: ....  --> ( gunicorn --config ./gunicorn.conf.py core.wsgi:application)

dg_run_sevicename1:
  <<: *dg
  restart: on-failure
  ports:
    - 9011:9011
  command: python manage.py sevicename

dg_run_sevicename2:
  <<: *dg
  restart: on-failure
  command: python manage.py sevicename2

dg_run_sevicename3:
...
```

Unless I agree to bascially multiple the same project source and use separate CMD or ENTRYPOINT at the end of each DOCKERFILE or YML declaration, it is perfectly fine.
It works. However the total images size is 3 times bigger than the origin folder itself.
Is it possible to do this in a better way?

Comment: Why can't you separate them into multiple containers ? If you don't you lose the benefit of having granularity between your microservices

Comment: Because in that case I will have to copy source all code for the whole project in each container.